# Reference Request: Smooth connectedness

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm looking for an explicit reference to the results:
If M is a smooth path-connected manifold, then any two points can be joined by a *smooth curve*.  There are many nice and clear proofs out there, that I know, but I'm looking for a citable reference.

Comment: What is the idea of the proof ? That you can smooth a piecewise smooth path ?

Comment: Basically you can patch together peicewise smooth paths (since you can do this in Euclidean space)...then you can smooth out the kinks in the initial smooth path using bump functions (or mollifiers probably would work to I guess).

Comment: Yeah, that is what I had in mind. Didnt know that result though.

Comment: Ya...now nly to find the reference hehe